# Casting Pointer of Stack Objects

Tags: c++, casting, message-queue

I'm building a messaging queue and currently I have two types of messages where one uses a template class.

```
class Message {
public:
    Message() : m_iMessageType( MESSAGE_UNDEFINED ) {}
    Message( int iMessageType ) : m_iMessageType( iMessageType ) {}
    int getType() { return m_iMessageType; }
    void setType( int iMessageType ) { m_iMessageType = iMessageType; }
private:
    int m_iMessageType;
}

template<typename T>
class DataMessage: public Message {
public:
    DataMessage() : Message(), m_oData( T() ) {}
    DataMessage( int iMessageType, T oData ) : Message( iMessageType ), m_oData( oData ) {}
    T getData() { return m_oData; }
    void setData( T oData ) { m_oData = oData; }
}
```

Which allows me send messages like this

```
Message toMessage( MESSAGE_GET_NAME );
DataMessage<std::string> fromMessage();
Messenger::getMessenger()->sendMessage( &toMessage, &fromMessage, CONSUMER );
std::cout << "Consumer name: " << fromMessage.getData() << std::endl;
```

However, this leads me to doing type casting while handling messages internally (casting `Message` to the appropriate `DataMessage<std::string>` for `fromMessage` in the above code). One of my consumers might look like this:

```
class Receiver {
public:
    Receiver() { Messenger::register( RECEIVER, this ); }
    handleMessage( Message* pIn, Message* pOut ) {
        // Ignoring the usual checking the message type
        (static_cast<DataMessage<std::string>*>( pOut ))->setData( "Consumer1" );
    }
```

Is it safe to cast a pointer if it points to an object on the stack of a calling method?

If I try the following code (which is wrong)

```
Message toMessage( MESSAGE_GET_NAME );
Message fromMessage; // The consumer is going to try and cast this to DataMessage<std::string>
Messenger::getMessenger()->sendMessage( &toMessage, &fromMessage, CONSUMER );
```

I don't get any segfaults or errors. Is something going horribly wrong and it'll creep up later during execution?

Comment: this is function declaration: `Message fromMessage();`. Use `Message fromMessage;` or `Message fromMessage{};`

Comment: Fixed both of your points

Comment: This is a context where you could use dynamic_cast. If it succeeds there is no reason to be concerned about accessing the pointed object. It does not matter where it is located as long as it stays valid during the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re asking two questions here.

> Is it safe to cast a pointer if it points to an object on the stack of a calling method?

Yes, this is safe. It doesn’t matter where the object lives as long as it’s really of the type you cast it to.

However, your design with `static_cast` is not really good style. `dynamic_cast` would at least return a null pointer if the object is not of the supplied type.

> Is something going horribly wrong and it'll creep up later during execution?

Yes. You casted a `Message` to `DataMessage`. That’s undefined behavior. Possibly you’ll end up simply reading whatever happens to be on the stack after the end of the Message object.